# How to compare two data sets using the diffdf package in R?

Tags: r, compare, comparison

I need to compare some pairs of huge data sets with each other based on the values in two columns as the key.
Each pair of data is indeed an older version of data and the updated version. So there are some IDs that do not match. I used semi_join to subset the data based on the IDs that are present in both data sets (I am not sure if it was necessary!).

```
df1_subset<- semi_join(df1, df2, by = c('ID1', 'ID2'))
df2_subset<- semi_join(df2, df1, by = c('ID1', 'ID2'))
```

I tried using the diffdf package. But I get the following error.

```
Error in diffdf(df1_subset, df2_subset, keys = "ID1", "ID2") :     
BY variables in BASE do not result in unique observations
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem please? As the data is very big I am not sure how to provide a sample here. If you have any other solutions I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keys = "ID1", "ID2"` is assigning the value `"ID1"` to the argument named `keys=`, and is assigning the unnamed argument `"ID2"` to the third unnamed argument (first two are your two subset frames), which happens to be `suppress_warnings=` (which should be logical).

I think you need to wrap the two IDs in `c(...)`.

```r
diffdf(df1_subset, df2_subset, keys = c("ID1", "ID2"))
```